# Assignment Level custom field update for tasks

Tags: vba, ms-project-server-2010

I am looking to update a Task Level custom field at the task assignment level. For ex, if a task has 2 resource assigned, i want one value to be "Offshore" and the other one to be "Onshore", when i view this task in the Task Usage view. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this thread? 
[Use CSOM to update project's custom fields](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/d79f22f2-7fd2-46af-b778-e189c8611120/use-csom-to-update-projects-custom-fields)

It's Project level but it may provide some further clues.
Actually, there's task level code at the bottom of that post so hopefully, that's what you need.